# Nuget Restore not installing content files

Tags: nuget-package-restore

So it appears that when installing a Nuget package that contains additional "non-assembly" files, those files are usually copied to the appropriate locations via a PowerShell script (install.ps1). And this works all well and good, until you check your project into source control; having ignored the packages folder (cause well that's the point right...), and someone else pulls the project. In that case, when that person restores the packages, those "non-assembly" files are not re-installed, despite being copying back down to the packages folder the PowerShell script doesn't run on restore. Forcing that person to determine which packages need to be literally uninstalled and reinstalled to get things working again.

Am I missing something? shouldn't that install script just run every time... I spent several hours today trying to determine why a colleague could not get their project running after pulling it out of source control for the first time.

Is there any work-around or fix for this besides creating yet another script to check for these missing files and:

```
Update-Package -Id packagename -reinstall
```

every single offending package, and run that as a pre-build event, just to get things working.

Comment: Just to add a specific example, this happens to the /bin/roslyn folder when using: Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, the folder will not be restored properly unless the Nuget package is explicitly uninstalled and reinstalled. My present fix, just include these binaries in source control...

Comment: I encountered this problem with 'nuget restore' today, and found also no alternative to the inclusion of binary in files in Git (normally binaries are in the .gitignore file).

Furthermore, this blog article also mention this behavior: https://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2017/01/13/nuget-package-restore-content-folder-and-version-control/

Comment: I'm having the same issue with some of our projects.  Too bad this isn't really a surprise given how janky nuget is.